# Unable to identify string encoding from barcode

Tags: ios, string, encoding, hex, barcode

I am tasked with decoding data stored on a Aztec barcode using an iOS device. I have access to the code that assembles the string sent to the barcode printer, but the printing itself is a black box.

As I step through the process, I can see that the string sent to the printer looks like this (note that other than the first 8 characters this is a encrypted string):

> _36_30_30_30_30_34_7c_5d_49_0b_ea_f7_93_ba_89_d2_c6_c2_41_2a_d7_1c_49_8c_6d_4b_5c_07_5a_ca_7a_6a_c6_d5_d0_6c_f7_20_76_5b_e0_18_46_93_7e_2a_30_0d_14_3a_1a_e5_66_7c_05_f9_df_96_8a_f1_45_a5_4a_6e_2f_89_3f_f0_93_1f_bc_3e_77_5b_27_0c_58_df_55_37_4c_ae_8a_e7_c3_c6_16_5b_57_db_7c_2d_2c_8b_1c_e3_a4_44_1b_c4_ba_6a_c6_98_93_ae_2d_20_6e_9f_e8_0f_eb_bc_9f_2e_8a_e7_cf_da_22_96_e1_74_de_b2_f0_29_ec_b1_c1_75_43_1f_b2_e5_1f_a5_f6_06_3e_97_a1_a1_93_f4_51_4a_c4_14_9f_1a_c2_5b_ba_02_45_44_2b_b3_c2_5b_ba_02_45_44_2b_b3_c2_5b_ba_02_45_44_2b_b3_c2_5b_ba_02_45_44_2b_b3_c2_5b_ba_02_45_44_2b_b3_c2_5b_ba_02_45_44_2b_b3_06_0b_12_75_85_8b_07_fb

And the printed barcode looks like this:

[image]

However, when I use a generic iOS barcode reader to read it back (I've tried a few), I get the following:

```
600004|]I�ê÷ºÒÆÂA*×�ImK\�ZÊzjÆÕÐl÷ v[à�F~*0
�:�åf|�ùßñE¥Jn/?ð�¼>w['�XßU7L®çÃÆ�[WÛ|-,�ã¤D�ÄºjÆ®- nè�PÐk^¡±xOS5·Óþ�ßá×D¢\���¥ö�>¡¡ôQJÄ��Â[º�ED+³Â[º�ED+³Â[º�ED+³Â[º�ED+³Â[º�ED+³Â[º�ED+³���u�û
```

This bares a resemblance the original string (for example the first few characters). But I have no idea what type of encoding this is, or how to translate it to the hex codes I was expecting to see.

I would love to know:

1) What am I looking at here?

2) How can I convert this string back into the original format?

Comment: @zaph Great idea, done. Thanks. Hopefully the quality is ok (it scanned ok from the screen for me). Also updated to mention its an Aztec.

Comment: I think you're wrong on all three counts there (but happy to be informed otherwise). 1) QR is a 2D barcode, which is still a barcode 2) This isn't a QR - QR is just one type of 2D barcode. This is an Aztec, another such type. 3) The string is both encrypted and then encoded in this instance. The 'before' content in my question is the encrypted string being sent to the printer. I'll see if I can tweak my question to make this clearer.

Comment: I do have the key and I'm comfortable with the decryption part, but just reading the barcode into a usable string is the obstacle. Thanks.

Comment: You should add the code you use to read from the barcode scanner.

Comment: @approxiblue I'm not using any code - just zapping the thing with barcode readers available on the App Store (tried a few, same results).

Comment: Since this is an encrypted string, what kind of hex codes are you expecting to see? What is a usable string in this context?

Comment: I'm just trying to get from the barcode image above, back to the quoted string that precedes it (the long list of hex codes interspersed with underscores). This quoted text is the already-encrypted string that I am asking the barcode printer to print. Once I can get that same string back by, I can handle the decryption part.

Comment: You might want to remove the decryption part from the question. It's not related to the problem you have (read from scanner), and at least 2 people have been thrown off the track by that detail already.

Comment: Are you sure the data you get is the *full* data?

Comment: @approxiblue Done, thanks.

Comment: @Thomas I corrected the output based on your reading.

Comment: Could you generate another set of data?

Comment: @Thomas - Yes. It might take some time but I will add it once I have it.

Comment: @zaph - that's the point - I have no such hex dump. That's what I'm trying to get to. I haven't written a line of code yet.

Comment: I used a barcode reader available on the app store (tried multiple, in fact). This is mentioned in the question. See also @Thomas' answer.

Comment: How did you generate the barcode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: For clarity, what you refer to as the encrypted string, I will refer to as the hex code, to further differentiate from the random-looking string at the end of your post.*

## Summary

I believe the encoding you're seeing in the string is a bungled ASCII/ISO-8859-1 encoding. It is omitting some characters, making it impossible to recover your original hex code from that string. After finding a scanner that properly handles the barcode, it turns out the barcode does not match your hex code.

## Encoding

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_Code#Character_set) that by default<sup>1</sup>, byte codes in Aztec are interpreted as ASCII when between 0 and 127, and as [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) when between 128 and 255. So when you substitute the letters and symbols you're getting with the proper hex values from those two encodings, you get the following:

> 36 30 30 30 30 34 7C 5D 49 EA F7 BA D2 C6 C2 41 2A D7 49 6D 4B 5C 5A CA 7A 6A C6 D5 D0 6C F7 20 76 5B E0 46 7E 2A 30 *0A* 3A E5 66 7C F9 DF F1 45 A5 4A 6E 2F 3F F0 BC 3E 77 5B 27 58 DF 55 37 4C AE E7 C3 C6 5B 57 DB 7C 2D 2C E3 A4 44 C4 BA 6A C6 AE 2D 20 6E **E8** 50 D0 6B 5E A1 B1 78 4F 53 35 B7 D3 FE DF E1 D7 44 A2 5C

This is similar to your encrypted hex code, but with some bytes omitted, and the stuff after the bolded `E8` byte is different. The omitted bytes are all from the `00` - `1F` and `80` - `9F` ranges. The `00` - `1F` range in ASCII are control codes, most of which are rarely used and not well supported by many applications. The other range is undefined in ISO-8859-1<sup>2</sup>. So any application trying to interpret these bytes as ASCII/ISO-8859-1 strings may result in unpredictable behaviour.

If you remove bytes from these ranges in your encrypted hex code, you get essentially<sup>3</sup> the same thing I got, up to the `E8` byte. The byte you have after `E8` is `0F`. I've never heard of this control code before, but [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29) it's called "Shift In" and its function is to "Return to regular character set after Shift Out." Since we're already having trouble with character sets, I can only assume that this control code is responsible for the interpretation errors after the `E8` byte.

**Edit:** One of your recent edits modified the string, and it now contains a few of these characters: �. This is Unicode's replacement character, a character that often replaces others when there is character encoding issues, or a process has trouble interpreting a particular character. In this case, it is replacing many bytes from the `00` - `1F` range, which are the ASCII controls. It remains impossible to recover. The `80` - `9F` range is still omitted.

## A better barcode reader

In order to properly interpret the barcode, you'll need a reader that does not interpret the hex code as encoded strings, but as a byte stream. At the very least, you need a reader that will still preserve the `00` - `1F` and `80` - `9F` ranges.

One such reader that I've found is [NeoReader](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/neoreader-qr-reader-barcode/id284973754?mt=8). It is entirely possible you've already tried it, but copy-pasting can cause errors with these special code ranges.

I scanned the code with it on an iOS 7 device, then hit the "Copy to Clipboard" button that the app provides. Then, I pasted the string at the top of [this converter](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) and hit convert. I usually use this converter for Unicode stuff, but other dedicated text to hex converters I found were not able to handle the string and its special codes. If you scroll down to the "Hexadecimal code points," you should be able to see the needed hexadecimal codes, though they are prefixed with an extra `00`<sup>4</sup>.

The string it produces (though take it with a grain of salt, I had some copy paste-errors and it appears the special controls were removed upon posting it):

> 600004|]I ê÷ºÒÆÂA*×ImK\ZÊzjÆÕÐl÷ v[àF~*0
>   :åf|ùßñE¥Jn/?ð¼>w[' XßU7L®çÃÆ[WÛ|-,ã¤DÄºjÆ®- nèPÐk^¡±xOS5·Óþßá×D¢\¥ö>¡¡ôQJÄÂ[ºED+³Â[ºED+³Â[ºED+³Â[ºED+³Â[ºED+³Â[ºED+³ uû

Hex code comparison (differences are marked by `< >`):

```
Your hex code:    36 30 30 30 30 34 7C 5D 49 0B EA F7 93 BA 89 D2 C6 C2 41 2A D7 1C 49 8C 6D 4B 5C 07 5A CA 7A 6A C6 D5 D0 6C F7 20 76 5B E0 18 46 93 7E 2A 30 <0D> 14 3A 1A E5 66 7C 05 F9 DF 96 8A F1 45 A5 4A 6E 2F 89 3F F0 93 1F BC 3E 77 5B 27 0C 58 DF 55 37 4C AE 8A E7 C3 C6 16 5B 57 DB 7C 2D 2C 8B 1C E3 A4 44 1B C4 BA 6A C6 98 93 AE 2D 20 6E 9F E8 0F <EB BC 9F 2E 8A E7 CF DA 22 96 E1 74 DE B2 F0 29 EC B1 C1 75 43 1F B2 E5> 1F A5 F6 06 3E 97 A1 A1 93 F4 51 4A C4 14 9F 1A C2 5B BA 02 45 44 2B B3 C2 5B BA 02 45 44 2B B3 C2 5B BA 02 45 44 2B B3 C2 5B BA 02 45 44 2B B3 C2 5B BA 02 45 44 2B B3 C2 5B BA 02 45 44 2B B3 06 0B 12 75 85 8B 07 FB
NeoReader string: 36 30 30 30 30 34 7C 5D 49 0B EA F7 93 BA 89 D2 C6 C2 41 2A D7 1C 49 8C 6D 4B 5C 07 5A CA 7A 6A C6 D5 D0 6C F7 20 76 5B E0 18 46 93 7E 2A 30 <0A> 14 3A 1A E5 66 7C 05 F9 DF 96 8A F1 45 A5 4A 6E 2F 89 3F F0 93 1F BC 3E 77 5B 27 0C 58 DF 55 37 4C AE 8A E7 C3 C6 16 5B 57 DB 7C 2D 2C 8B 1C E3 A4 44 1B C4 BA 6A C6 98 93 AE 2D 20 6E 9F E8 0F <81 50 D0 6B 5E A1 B1 78 4F 53 35 B7 D3 FE 1F DF E1 90 D7 44 A2 5C 00 19> 1F A5 F6 06 3E 97 A1 A1 93 F4 51 4A C4 14 9F 1A C2 5B BA 02 45 44 2B B3 C2 5B BA 02 45 44 2B B3 C2 5B BA 02 45 44 2B B3 C2 5B BA 02 45 44 2B B3 C2 5B BA 02 45 44 2B B3 C2 5B BA 02 45 44 2B B3 06 0B 12 75 85 8B 07 FB
```

## The difference explained

It turns out, that the barcode does not actually match your hex code. Where our two codes diverge, at that `0F` byte, the barcode actually follows what NeoReader suggests. This is shown in the image below, which is zoomed in on the bottom-right quadrant of the barcode (the blue lines indicate parts that do not encode data, they are to help orient the scanner).

[image: Partial barcode decoding]

I managed to manually<sup>5</sup> decode that section of barcode, with help from [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtlqYx6e1TE). Your barcode, however, does not use the string encoding method shown there, as it uses a [binary shift escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_Code#Character_set) to work with 8-bit values. From there I believe the one `0A` <-> `0D` difference is due to a copy paste error on my part.

Unfortunately, since the printer is a black box to you, it does not appear as though you can fix this problem yourself.

## Footnotes

1. I could not find an Aztec Code specification, but the behaviour seems to be relatively consistent with the default.
2. [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) is essentially a superset of ASCII, but it *technically* leaves the ASCII control code range undefined. This is usually ignored in practice.
3. The only difference is the italicized `0A` character I have, which is a new line character. Your string has `0D`, another new line character. Different systems handle new lines differently, and its not uncommon for them to automatically change the new line characters. Unlike most other ASCII control codes, new line characters are usually well supported.
4. The reason for this is complicated. Glossing over a few details, I believe that upon hitting the convert button, it is first converted to UTF-16 (Javascript's native string encoding). The byte values for the ASCII/ISO-8859-1 characters are the same in UTF-16. However, UTF-16 is a 16-bit encoding rather than an 8-bit encoding, hence, the extra `00`.
5. That was painful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I've tried the following online barcode reader:

- [intbusoft](http://intbusoft.com/online/aztecreader/) : server error
- [onlinebarcodereader](http://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/) : no code found
- [datasymbol](http://www.datasymbol.com/barcode-recognition-sdk/barcode-reader/online-barcode-decoder.html) : code different from yours
- [pqscan](http://www.pqscan.com/online-demo/barcode-scanner/) : no code found
- [zxing](https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx) : code longer than your.

This makes me think that your bar-code may be not so well construct...

Here's your output:

```
600004|]Iê÷ºÒÆÂA*×ImK\ZÊzjÆÕÐl÷ v[àF~*0
:åf|ùßñE¥Jn/?ð¼>w['XßU7L®çÃÆ[WÛ|-,ã¤DÄºjÆ®- nèPÐk^¡±xOS5·Óþßá×D¢\
```

and here's the one from zxing:

```
600004|]I�ê÷ºÒÆÂA*×�ImK\�ZÊzjÆÕÐl÷ v[à�F~*0
�:�åf|�ùßñE¥Jn/?ð�¼>w['�XßU7L®çÃÆ�[WÛ|-,�ã¤D�ÄºjÆ®- nè�PÐk^¡±xOS5·Óþ�ßá×D¢\���¥ö�>¡¡ôQJÄ��Â[º�ED+³Â[º�ED+³Â[º�ED+³Â[º�ED+³Â[º�ED+³Â[º�ED+³���u�û
```

(*maybe* this difference is due to a copy/paste manipulation on your side)

---

This is the matching that I was able to find:

```
6  0  0  0  0  4  |  ]  I   �  ê  ÷     º     Ò  Æ  Â 
36 30 30 30 30 34 7c 5d 49  0b ea f7 93 ba 89 d2 c6 c2

A  *  ×  �  I     m  K  \  �  Z  Ê  z  j  Æ  Õ  Ð  l 
41 2a d7 1c 49 8c 6d 4b 5c 07 5a ca 7a 6a c6 d5 d0 6c

÷  v  [  à  �  F     ~  *  0  �     :  �  å  f     | 
f7 20 76 5b e0 18 46 93 7e 2a 30 0d 14 3a 1a e5 66 7c

�  ù  ß        ñ  E  ¥  J  n  /     ?  ð     �  ¼  > 
05 f9 df 96 8a f1 45 a5 4a 6e 2f 89 3f f0 93 1f bc 3e

w  [  '  �  X  ß  U  7  L   ®     ç  Ã  Æ  �  [  W  Û  
77 5b 27 0c 58 df 55 37 4c  ae 8a e7 c3 c6 16 5b 57 db 

|  -  ,  �     ã  ¤  D  �  Ä  º  j  Æ        ®  -     
7c 2d 2c 8b 1c e3 a4 44 1b c4 ba 6a c6 98 93 ae 2d 20 

n     è  �  P 
6e 9f e8 0f eb
```

And this *seems* to be some [Unicode UCS-2](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ucs2.html) encoding.

After this, I can't explain the difference between output and expected hexadecimal values

Comment: @zaph you're kind of true... But you can't says it's random with 60+ char matching....

Comment: @zaph then how do you explain that if you decode the 113st bytes of hexa given by the OP you get the *exact* same chars?

Comment: "the hexa values given are already encrypted" - yup. Its getting a reliable decoding, not a decryption, I'm after. I can decrypt the string just fine, if only I can read the darned thing from the barcode.